# When I call a person doctor

Tags: titles

If I call a person doctor, instead of Doctor XXX, will this person assumes that I forget his name?

When I talk with another person, I said:" I wish to study in doctor's lab." At that time, the doctor is just next to me.

Comment: I have the impression that this is more common in India.  Also: We did that in Sir's class.  We learned that from Miss.  These are uncommon in the US.

Comment: @GEdgar well, not only uncommon, I would actually say ungrammatical (in American English), but I'm not exactly a language expert. Perhaps something on [english.SE] addresses it.

Comment: @GEdgar I should say it is indeed uncommon in my country, China. I hope it is not offensive in the US.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is not common in my experience (first-language English speaker in the US) to call anyone just "Doctor" unless they are a medical doctor. In non-medical settings, you should always use their surname after the title.

On the other hand, it is OK to use just "Professor", if you are speaking to the person.

So you could ask, "Professor, can I take the exam tomorrow?" But not "Doctor, can I take the exam tomorrow?"

If you are talking to someone else, you should always use the surname, don't just call the person "professor" or "doctor" as if that was a name.

Comment: @neo don't worry no one in the really cares

Comment: @StrongBad I hope so. I am afraid he would thought I had forgotten his name, since it's my first time to meet him.

Comment: I agree that this is not likely to cause anyone offense. Especially in academia where we are used to second-language speakers.

Comment: @Neo Honestly, if the person has made it to being a professor they have forgotten so many people's name at this point that it likely didn't even occur to them that you forgot their name, and even if they thought you did they probably wouldn't be deeply hurt by it. They'd have to be amazingly thin-skinned, and that kind of person rarely makes it all that far in academia.

Comment: And if you use "Doc", people will think you're Bugs Bunny.

Comment: @jab that or Marty Mcfly!

Comment: I admit I'm not a native speaker, but I think that in some cases it is fine to use "Doctor" by itself when addressing someone, like in: "Good evening, Doctor". On the other hand, I agree that I would never refer to someone by their title alone when talking about them with a third person.

Comment: @A.P. - yes, that is OK, but only when the person is a medical doctor. It would sound completely out of place if the person works in some other area such as engineering or humanities.

Comment: @A.P. I feel Oswald Veblen is right.

Comment: I agree, except I do use it with engineering PhD graduates sometimes, completely ironically and for comedic effect.

Comment: @JAB can you tell me why Bugs Bunny?

Comment: @Neo https://youtu.be/pwLn_His9Yw